# How to find the index of matching elements in a list using Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```py
l1 = [1, 46, 8, 9, 4, 76, 797, 342, 3, 5, 67, 42, 87]
l2 = [42, 34, 5, 78, 8, 9, 4]
```

I want to find out the index of `l1` that have matches in `l2`.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `print([i for i, v in enumerate(l1) if v in set(l2)])`

Answer (score 0):

Naive method:

```py
for i in range(len(l1)):
    try:
        if l1[i] in l2:
            print(i)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

You can also use a oneliner, which is more efficient because the lookup in a set is done in constant time, credits to @Matthias for pointing that out:

```py
[i for i, v in enumerate(l1) if v in set(l2)]
```

Comment: if you use a set for `l2` the complexity is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with enumerate and set is that it does not keep the order, here's a code that does this:

```
print([l1.index(k) for k in l2 if k in l1])
```